# Submit a form using Enter key with "@material-ui/core/Button" in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, material-ui

Here is my form in render method which is for user sign-in.

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
    <LockOutlinedIcon />
  </Avatar>
  <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
    Sign in
  </Typography>

  <TextField variant="outlined" margin="normal" fullWidth id="email"
    label="Email Address" name="email" onChange={this.handleEmailChange}
  />
  <TextField variant="outlined" margin="normal" fullWidth
    name="password" onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}
  />
  {loginError && (
    <Typography component="p" className={classes.errorText}>
      Incorrect email or password.
    </Typography>
  )}

  <Button type="button" fullWidth variant="contained" color="primary"
    className={classes.submit} onClick={this.handleSubmit}
  >
    Sign In
  </Button>
</form>
```

And the following is my handle submit method.

```
handleSubmit = () => {
  const { dispatch } = this.props;
  const { email, password } = this.state;
  dispatch(loginUser(email, password));
};
```

How can I submit the form by pressing the `Enter` key? I am using the standard Material UI `Button` component.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try the following by making the button of type `"submit"` instead. This should enable form submit using the enter key:

```
<Button type="submit" fullWidth variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.submit}>
  Sign In
</Button>
```

Also with type `"submit"` you don't need `onClick`, because clicking a submit button triggers the form `submit` event by default.

Comment: Now it's working. I had to use event.preventDefault() in handleSubmit to stop reloading page. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `type="submit"` as for the button
Ex:

```
    <Button 
        type="submit" 
        fullWidth 
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        className={classes.submit}
    >
        Sign In
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `type=submit` in `Button` did not work for me.
You could try with this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59147255). It uses a `UseEffect` hook which works in React.

Comment: Chances are, your <Button> is not inside a <form>