# React keypress event taking only initial state values and not updated values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, use-effect, use-state

I am creating a React application in which I have one state called input which is taking input from user. I want that when I press enter key, alert should display the input which is getting set in state. However, on clicking <kbd>enter</kbd> key, only default value set in input state is getting displayed.

But when I click on a button (which I have created to display the input in alert), then the input displayed in alert is correct.

Please see the code snippet below for reference:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

export default function ShowAlertExample() {

  const [input, setInput ] = useState('1');
  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  }

  const handleShowAlert = () => {
    alert(input);
  }

  const checkKeyPress = (e) =>{
    const { key, keyCode } = e;
    console.log(key, keyCode)
    if (keyCode === 13 ) {
      alert(input);
    }
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress)
    return ()=>{
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress)
    }
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <div>
      <header className="App-header">
        <input value={input} onChange={handleInputChange} />
       <button onClick={handleShowAlert}>Show Alert</button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I made one change which can be seen in the code snippet below. I removed the `[]` from dependency list of `useEffect()` and it started working fine, but now the issue is it is adding and removing event listener each time I add something to input. This is not a good practice I guess if we are creating a big application.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

export default function ShowAlertExample() {

  const [input, setInput ] = useState('1');
  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  }

  const handleShowAlert = () => {
    alert(input);
  }

  const checkKeyPress = (e) =>{
    const { key, keyCode } = e;
    console.log(key, keyCode)
    if (keyCode === 13 ) {
      alert(input);
    }
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress)
    console.log("event listener added")
    return ()=>{
      console.log("event listener removed")
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress)
    }
  })
  
  return (
    <div>
      <header className="App-header">
        <input value={input} onChange={handleInputChange} />
       <button onClick={handleShowAlert}>Show Alert</button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is there anyway I can add event listener with the desired functionality without causing any performance issue. That is when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, the alert should display the correct input. I have referred to the below Stack Overflow post and tried using `useCallback()` but it didn't work out.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565444/how-to-register-event-with-useeffect-hooks#:~:text=hooks%20to%20below-,useEffect(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20window.,the%20effect%20once%2C%20imitating%20componentDidMount%20.

Comment: What is the purpose of `checkKeyPress` function? Perhaps if you explained your use-case we could suggest a more optimal solution. I.e. It is usually better to just attach an `onKeyDown` handler to the inputs that care about that event. This removes the stale enclosure issue. See [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-keypress-event-taking-only-initial-state-values-and-not-updated-values-j4ud7?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Hi @DrewReese - Thanks for your comment . My use case : I am making an application where I have provided keyboard shortcuts . When user clicks 'O' , a dialog box opens where there are radio buttons, checkboxes and text fields (pre-populated using some initial state) and a submit button . I want that when user presses enter key , I can use the data set in the states and form a JSON packet and submit them in POST request . Thats why I want to add checkKeyPress function to the event listener in useEffect() so that in checkKeyPress() , I can call submit() request .

Comment: Yes, you mention submitting a request and I agree with @Lakshya that perhaps a better solution would be to use a semantic form with `onSubmit` handler to access the form fields. If you store the form field values in component state then you'll always have the issue of needing to re-enclose current state values in any callbacks. The alternative to state is to use a React ref per input/field and access the current value when you need to.

Comment: Drew and Lakshya - Thanks to both for quick replies . One more question . My second code snippet which I posted above works fine . Only reason I wasn't using it was because it was adding and removing checkKeyPress to the event handler on every key press . But as @Lakshya told, we need to bind and unbind event handler after each state update . Can you tell if I can go ahead with this code as I don't need to add any dependency list here or add event handler directly to element .  Or is it not a good practice to go with this solution (refer to my second code snippet above) .

Comment: The `useEffect` ***without*** dependency will remove and re-add the event listener and callback on ***every*** render of the component, versus ***only when*** the dependency updates. While it may not be an issue with resetting the handler it's still unnecessary to do so on every render.

Answer (score 14):

Since you always require the latest state value of `input`, you will have to add `checkKeyPress` to your `useEffect`'s dependency list and `checkKeyPress` should itself have `input` in the wrapper `useCallback` deps list.

```
 const checkKeyPress = useCallback((e) => {
    const { key, keyCode } = e;
    console.log(key, keyCode);
    if (keyCode === 13) {
      alert(input);
    }
  },[input]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress);
    };
  }, [checkKeyPress]);
```

In your older code ,an empty array in `useEffect` means that you're adding an event listener to the `checkKeyPress` that was available after first render. Now that `checkKeyPress` closes over the default value of `input`.

You need to ensure that every time that `input` updates, latest `checkKeyPress` (one which closes over the latest `input`) is added as an **event handler** and the old one removed.

Comment: Hi @Lakshya Thakur - Thanks for your reply . Yes this is a possible solution but it would add and remove checkKeyPress() to the eventListener each time some input is entered . In a big application where I have many input states like text fields, radio buttons and checkboxes and I want user to submit the form using enter key , this may cause performance issues as I will have to add several input fields in the dependency list of useCallback() which will make useEffect() run again and again .

Comment: If your event listener deals with the react state then you always will need to bind and unbind event handlers as state updates. Otherwise you will be dealing with stale state. As per my current experience, there isn't any work around for this particular use-case. Also let's consider a form. You probably won't want an event listener on window but a submit event on form element. React in the bg will also be binding/unbind new event handlers as your JSX renders again and so does form.

Comment: Also It will be more performant than explicitly binding events to window since react uses event delegation internally.

Comment: Thanks for you insights . Both solutions onSubmit() and using useCallback() are good . I'll go with onSubmit() as it is conventionally considered a good practice . Thanks for your help .

Comment: adding checkKeyPress event in useEffect save my life. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You truly saved my life. In the literal sense of it.

Answer (score 4):

## Issue

You've enclosed the initial `input` state value in the `checkKeyPress` callback for the "keydown" event. Each time the callback is invoked you are accessing a stale state enclosure.

## Solution

Instead of trying to use a global keyDown handler just attach an event handler directly to the elements you want to a callback to respond to, which is the standard way to handle DOM interactions in React anyway. This removes the stale enclosure and makes it a standard callback.

```
function ShowAlertExample() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("1");
  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleShowAlert = () => {
    alert(input);
  };

  const checkKeyPress = (e) => {
    const { key, keyCode } = e;
    console.log(key, keyCode);
    if (keyCode === 13) {
      alert(input);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <header className="App-header">
        <input
          value={input}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          onKeyDown={checkKeyPress} // <-- attach event handler
        />
        <button onClick={handleShowAlert}>Show Alert</button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-keypress-event-taking-only-initial-state-values-and-not-updated-values]

Comment: Just for clarity sake, here also on each state change, a new checkKeyPress is being bound and previous one unbound for the keydown event. It's just that now React is handling that for us and already React uses event delegation for better performance.

Comment: @DrewReese - Thanks for the solution . Only doubt I have is if user clicks outside the input box and then presses 'Enter' key , then it may not work . However, I agree with you and Lakshya that best solution is to use onSubmit() in this case . Actually I wasn't using <form /> element here but was creating input fields inside <div> , so faced this issue . I think I should use that . Thanks .

Comment: @satyam Yes, this would only work while the input has focus, but also why I asked more about your use case. If you need a global keypress handler then listening on the window/document is the way to go, and you would just need to optimize on accessing the field values.