# Enter key not working for tab/keyboard accessibility in react app

Tags: reactjs, accessibility

So I have a React app where I'm trying to improve keyboard accessibility. According to https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/, the 'enter' and the spacebar key should "click" on focused buttons. I can see from the UI that the buttons are coming into focus, but enter/spacebar only works on **some** of them.

Is there an explanation for this, or a fix?

Comment: Odds are there is a `preventDefault()` (or React equivalent) intercepting the clicks and stopping them working. Unfortunately without anything to test against the best we can say is to check out the event handlers attached to the buttons that don't work and see if they are intercepting clicks (or bound to `mouseDown` etc.). Also check that they are actually `<button>` elements and not `<div>`s styled like buttons, if they are divs swap them for buttons and try it.

Comment: Definitely need to see your code, but a potential answer here using the "submit" button type you get access to the enter key method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211672/how-to-submit-a-form-using-enter-key-in-react-js